# Installing DESeq2 in Ubuntu

Tags: deseq2, software-installation, linux

I am trying to install DESeq2 in my Ubuntu with R version 3.5.1. According to the package repository in Bioconductor the version should be 3.5.

```
> R.version

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          5.1                         
year           2018                        
month          07                          
day            02                          
svn rev        74947                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
nickname       Feather Spray
```

then I attempt to install DESeq2, following the instructions in Bioconductor:

```
> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
       install.packages("BiocManager")
   BiocManager::install("DESeq2", version = "3.8"
```

and at the end I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘annotate’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘GenomicRanges’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘genefilter’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘geneplotter’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘SummarizedExperiment’ had non-zero exit status
8: In install.packages(pkgs = doing, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘DESeq2’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have visited $2*10^{9999}$ discussions on this issue and none of them helped me solving the problem. In addition, I didn't have any problem installing other packages like limma and edgeR, so I assume that this might be specific to DESeq2 or one of it's dependencies.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I used to have an issue where I had to run R-studio with sudo or my OS wouldn't allow me to install packages.

Comment: @Pallie, thanks! I had similar issues with other packages but in this case I run rstudio with sudo and it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

First I installed this libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev
```

I then installed RCurl:

```
BiocManager::install("RCurl")
```

and lastly:

```
BiocManager::install("DESeq2", version = "3.8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just typing,

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
```

Without all the proceeding if statement? If this doesn't install correctly nothing else will.  Personally I would be tempted install each of the named libraries independently. If that works okay, e.g. its not a problem with the mirrors then I'd contact the developer michaelisaiahlove at gmail.com

Comment: BiocManager is successfully installed. The problem is with DESeq2...

Comment: Thanks it worked! I will post the answer for others with the same problem

Comment: Cool, happy to hear! Systems admin is the bane of every bioinformatician.

Comment: I noticed that some packages sometimes failed to compile depending on the version of gcc present on the system. So far, most of my problems were solved using a minimal R 3.5 installation, gcc 4.9 and trying to install everything using Bioconductor.